# Get address knowing longitude and latitude with Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

**What I have since now:**

*The beyond code locates me on the map and tells me my actual longitude and latitude and it also displays a map with a marker on my current position*

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (pos)
{
  var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
  var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
  var H = parseInt(screen.height)-parseInt(44);
 document.getElementById("canvas").style.height=H+'px';
    $("#latitude").val (lat);
  $("#longitude").val (lng); 
  
var myZoom = 17;
var myMarkerIsDraggable = true;
var myCoordsLenght = 6;
var defaultLat = lat;
var defaultLng = lng;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
    zoom: myZoom,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(defaultLat, defaultLng),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(defaultLat, defaultLng),
    draggable: myMarkerIsDraggable
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function(evt){
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(myCoordsLenght);
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(myCoordsLenght);
});

map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
myMarker.setMap(map);
});
```

**What I want to achieve:**

Based on the above code which gives me my current long and lat I want to convert them into address and display it on an input. Since now I have the following:

```
<input id="latitude" type="text" name="latitude" value=""/>
<input id="longitude" name="longitude" type="text" value=""/>
<input id="address" name="address" type="text" value=""/>
```

The first 2 display latitude and longitude into an input which based on a form I save into a database, I want that inside the 3rd input I have the address which I want along with latitude and longitude to save them into a database.

Comment: See here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: It's not permitted by google to store these data